# Fascia, drip edge, starter shingle, code, in Texas

Tags: roof

I may have to get a contractor to repair or redo my roof. I guess the previous one did not do it right as I see starter shingle flush with drip edge, and the drip edge attached to the fascia. Resulting in obvious rot damage to fascia.  From online videos it appears to me that the order is,  from home, something like: fascia board, then 1/2 inch gap, then drip edge, 1/2 inch gap, and finally edge of starter shingle.

The issue is the  [Texas Windstorm Insurance Association (TWIA) code](https://www.tdi.texas.gov/wind/documents/1bldgcodewindconstse.pdf). Presumably the hanging portion of roof shingle beyond its supporting wood frame can contribute to wind lifting the roof. So in essence if you try to protect your fascia and soffit from the damage of  rain then you risk loosing your roof!

What is a smart solution?

If the previous roofer made an error can I do a repair? For example, can I extend the drip edge beyond the starter shingle? Or do I have choose between the cost of re-roof or cost of fascia damage.

Exactly what is the code in layman's terms? I should be able to make sure my contractor knows what is involved. And does it right.

Answer (score 1):

Laying down a roof starts from the bottom and goes toward the peak. Trying to repair something like the drip edge or lowest run of shingles is almost never going to give a good result without starting over.

If you need to replace the fascia board, you mentioned rotting, usually also involves stripping the roof, especially when there is an existing metal edging installed over it and maybe even nailed into it.

In my experience in working on roofs hanging the shingles a small amount over the drip edge does not significantly increase the ability of wind to rip the shingles off the roof. Of course it is best if the roof is laid down with the very first course using a starter roll instead of shingles. Good quality starter roll has a row of tar strips a short distance up from its lower edge to which the tabs of the first row of shingles are meant to bond.